# My if Statements will default to the wrong one

Tags: java, if-statement

```
    if (SuperTotal [0] == SuperTotal [1] && SuperTotal [0] == SuperTotal [2])
    {
        System.out.println ("1First: " + name [0] + ", " + name [1] + ", " + name [2]);
    }
    //1=2 & 1 > 3
    else if (SuperTotal [0] == SuperTotal [1] && SuperTotal [0] > SuperTotal [2])
    {
        System.out.println ("2First: " + name [0] + ", " + name [1] + "\nSecond: " + name [2]);
    }
    //2=3 & 2 > 1
    else if (SuperTotal [1] == SuperTotal [2] && SuperTotal [1] > SuperTotal [0])
    {
        System.out.println ("3First: " + name [1] + ", " + name [2] + "\nSecond: " + name [0]);
    }
    //1=3 & 1 > 2
    else if (SuperTotal [0] == SuperTotal [2] && SuperTotal [0] > SuperTotal [1])
    {
        System.out.println ("4First: " + name [0] + ", " + name [2] + "\nSecond: " + name [1]);
    }
    //1=2 & 1 < 3
    else if (SuperTotal [0] == SuperTotal [1] && SuperTotal [0] < SuperTotal [2])
    {
        System.out.println ("5First: " + name [2] + "'nSecond: " + name [0] + ", " + name [1]);
    }
    //1=3 & 1 < 2
    else if (SuperTotal [0] == SuperTotal [2] && SuperTotal [0] < SuperTotal [1])
    {
        System.out.println ("7First: " + name [0] + "\nSecond: " + name [1] + ", " + name [2]);
    }
    //2=3 & 2 < 1
    else if (SuperTotal [1] == SuperTotal [2] && SuperTotal [1] < SuperTotal [0])
    {
        System.out.println ("7First: " + name [0] + "\nSecond: " + name [1] + ", " + name [2]);
    }
    else if (SuperTotal [0] > SuperTotal [1] && SuperTotal [0] > SuperTotal [2] && (SuperTotal [1] < SuperTotal [2] || SuperTotal [1] > SuperTotal [2]))
    {
    }
```

So basically for some reason even when given different numbers that should use different "if" statements it defaults to the one that says 2=3 & 2 < 1.

Do you see anything that I'm doing wrong, or anything that could be more efficiently done?

Comment: The random numbers in the System.out.println (); were just to make sure that the right one was being output.

Comment: I am certain it can be done more efficiently (programmer-wise). I have no idea how, at least not until you explain what you are trying to do (in words) - as I don't really have the patience to read the repetitive code with tiny variations.

Comment: What is stored in SuperTotal array ?

Comment: I see you're using 2 arrays but you haven't indicated how the two are related.  I can't make much of a judgement of the output without knowing more.

Comment: double Variables that have been gained over a long process. It's a "Dive competition score calculator." But for extra marks (it's an assignment) I can rank the "divers." But I am using their total scores sorted from highest to lowest (higher score being better). That's where this comes in.

Comment: And the name variable is just a list of names

Comment: @RossParker It would be helpful to folks to edit your original question with some of the elaborations you've made. That way, it will be easier to read and understand what you'd like help solving.

Comment: @brightmatrix I can;t make it easier to look at. But I can try to re- explain the issue I'm having.

Comment: So when I run the program let's say SuperTotal[0] = 5, SuperTotal[1] = 5 and SuperTotal[2] = 10. It shoudl use the if statement that says 1=2 & 1 < 3 above it. But the code will automatically just say that person 1 was in first place and the others were in second. In other words. It uses the if statement that has 2=3 & 2 < 1 above it. Does that help?

Comment: @RossParker Sure, that's exactly what I meant ... just summing up some of the conversation you've had with other folks in the comments so it's clearer in your original question.

Comment: More important, explain what you are _actually_ trying to accomplish.  That code can surely be refactored to be much simpler, but only if we know what you think it's supposed to do.

Comment: I have to figure out which number is greater of the 3. SuperTotal[0], SuperTotal[1] and SuperTotal[2]. These three things represent scores given to the top 3 divers of a competition. The numbers have been pre sorted so that they are highest to lowest. My goal is to output who was 1st, 2nd and 3rd.

Comment: Please make sure that your question is complete as described here in more detail: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . You will get quicker and better responses on complete questions.

Answer (score 0):

for //1=3 & 1 < 2 output names are wrong

```
else if (SuperTotal [0] == SuperTotal [2] && SuperTotal [0] < SuperTotal [1])
{
    System.out.println ("7First: " + name [1] + "\nSecond: " + name [0] + ", " + name [2]);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for that. I probably would never have seen that. :)